# Pug.compile : unexpected text ";pug_"

Tags: node.js, templates, pug, lexer

I'm working on the password reset functionnality in a node.js express app, for that I intend to compile a pug template, it's output is sent to the user with a reset token as a mail.

Pug is already implemented and working as a view engine in the express app but I'm using it's API directly in some endpoints.

- pug version: 2.0.3 (also tried 2.0.0)
- node version : 8.11.3

.js

```
var locals = {name: user.name, resetLink: link};

var template = pug.compileFile(path.join(__dirname, "../views/emails/reset.pug")),
    html = pug.render(template, locals)
```

.pug template

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= "Password reset"
    body
        block content
            p Hello #{name}!
            p Here is your
                a(href="#{resetLink}" target="_blank") reset link
```

I've tried pug.compile & pug.compileFile all my attempts failed with this kind of error which doesn't lead me anywhere.
Several templates from me and the net have been used to test it out with the same results

```
C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:60
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Pug:3:1
    1| function template(locals) {var pug_html = "", pug_mixins = {}, pug_interp;var pug_debug_filename, pug_
debug_line;try {;var locals_for_with = (locals || {});(function (name, token) {;pug_debug_line = 1;pug_debug_
filename = "C:\\DEV\\Workspace\\Node\\express-auth\\views\\emails\\reset.pug";
    2| pug_html = pug_html + "\u003Chtml\u003E";
  > 3| ;pug_debug_line = 2;pug_debug_filename = "C:\\DEV\\Workspace\\Node\\express-auth\\views\\emails\\reset
.pug";
-------^
    4| pug_html = pug_html + "\u003Chead\u003E";
    5| ;pug_debug_line = 3;pug_debug_filename = "C:\\DEV\\Workspace\\Node\\express-auth\\views\\emails\\reset
.pug";
    6| pug_html = pug_html + "\u003Ctitle\u003E";

unexpected text ";pug_"
    at makeError (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-error\index.js:32:13)
    at Lexer.error (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:59:15)
    at Lexer.fail (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1441:10)
    at Lexer.advance (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1501:15)
    at Lexer.callLexerFunction (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1456:23)
    at Lexer.getTokens (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1512:12)
    at lex (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:12:42)
    at Object.lex (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:99:27)
    at Function.loadString [as string] (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:44:
24)
    at compileBody (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:86:18)
    at Object.exports.compile (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:242:16)
    at handleTemplateCache (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:215:25)
    at Object.exports.render (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:396:10)
    at RandomBytes.ondone (C:\DEV\Workspace\Node\express-auth\routes\index.js:124:18)
```

There is few documentation on that problem, one track would be trailing spaces around locals or blocks in the template file, I tried removing them without success.

The template used is compiled and rendered well when used with express view engine.

Thanks in advance,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compileFile` returns a render function, not a bare template.

From their [documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugcompilefilepath-options):

```
var pug = require('pug');

// Compile a function
var fn = pug.compileFile('path to pug file', options);

// Render the function
var html = fn(locals);
// => '<string>of pug</string>'
```

So your code should be:

```
var locals = {name: user.name, resetLink: link};

var template = pug.compileFile(path.join(__dirname, "../views/emails/reset.pug")),
    html = template(locals);
```